# SQL Server disable triggers within or outside a loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

Should I disable then enable triggers within the loop so that it disables them, then updates, then re-enables, for each item, or should I disable them once at the start of the script and re-enable them once at the end of the script?

For a basic example,  let's say for the sake of argument I have two tables:

table_A has fields `firstname`,`surname`,`id`

table_B has fields `firstname`,`surname`

For this exercise the `id` field of `table_A` is a sequential integer from 1 with no skipped numbers.

The following SQL will go through each record in `table_A` and insert `firstname` and `surname` into `table_B`:

```
DECLARE   @Counter INT, 
      @RowCount INT

SET @Counter = 1
SET @RowCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_A)

WHILE @Counter <= @RowCount BEGIN   

    INSERT INTO table_B (firstname,surname)
    SELECT firstname,surname
    FROM table_A
    WHERE id = @Counter

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1

END
```

If `table_B` has triggers defined on it and I want to disable those triggers, as I see it I have two options: I can disable the triggers once at the start of the script and once at the end, or immediately before and after the `insert`. Is there a best practice for this, and am I right in thinking that I should minimise the overall time they're disabled by disabling them within the `while` ... `end` loop, on the grounds that a number of other people and clients may be using the database at the same time?

Comment: Since your concern is around concurrency, I'd say neither. I'd change the triggers to detect that this special piece of code is the one responsible for a particular set of inserts and just `return` immediately rather than running the rest of the trigger code.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for your comment, I'll definitely look into that for future use, can I get the trigger to identify that it's particular inserts running (in fact my real code is doing updates rather than inserts)? I'm looking at automating this process eventually, so if I can get it to recognise that it is this particular script running then that would be really useful

Comment: Why are you using a loop to do these updates? Disable the triggers, issue a set based query to insert/update the rows and then enable the triggers again.

Comment: What we've done in the past is use `CONTEXT_INFO` - the outer query calls `SET CONTEXT_INFO` and applies a distinctive pattern, then inside the trigger it checks `CONTEXT_INFO()` and if it matches (one of) the distinctive patterns that we're using, the trigger exits.

Comment: @Tony it's part of a datafeed process, so for each record in the datafeed from our supplier it has a to first check existence in our own database, and if it exists it has to update pricing, discount rates, product names etc. Any errors or changes it makes it also has to export to an exception table so we can see what it has and hasn't done.

Comment: @Damien that sounds good I will go and experiment with that

Comment: @Tony plus I'm only a beginner and I don't understand how to use set based queries yet :)

Comment: @Tony, I've just been reading about set-based, I found this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches ... The last yellow block of sample code is actually what mine is doing, it inserts all my records into a @table variable, adding `Number INT IDENTITY(1,1),` as one of the fields, but isn't what they're doing still cursor-based? I guess I should be posting this as a separate question

Comment: @laurencemadill - I've added an answer as it's easier to format the code than in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason to be using a loop for the updates I would disable the triggers at the start of the script, process the inserts/updates as a single set based query and then enable the triggers again.

For your `INSERT` statement you could simply do

```
INSERT INTO table_B (id, firstname, surname)
SELECT id, firstname, surname FROM table_A
```

but from your comments you don't just want to copy the rows from one table to another, you need to update rows that exist and insert those which do not. For that you can use [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) to [insert, update or delete data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

> [Merge] performs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table based
>   on the results of a join with a source table. For example, you can
>   synchronize two tables by inserting, updating, or deleting rows in one
>   table based on differences found in the other table.

For your example statement you could use

```
MERGE table_B 
USING (SELECT firstname, surname FROM table_A)
  ON table_B.id = table_A.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
  SET table_B.firstname = table_A.firstname,
      table_B.surname = table_A.surname
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(id, firstname, surname)
  VALUES(table_A.id, table_A.forename, table_A.surname);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is probably exactly what I should be doing...I'd better go and play with this on my test database.